# Grails currencyInstance.properties not set after currencyInstance.properties = params

Tags: grails, grails-controller

I am using Grails 2.3.3

In CurrencyController. after

```
currencyInstance.properties = params
```

currencyInstance.properties doesn't change.

But currencyInstance.properties change if I set

```
currencyInstance.code = params.code
currencyInstance.name = params.name
```

Here is my params :

```
println "Here is params: $params"

==> Here is params: [id:34, name:Australian dollar 1, code:AUD, version:4]
```

And domain

```
class Currency {

    String code;
    String name;

    static constraints = {
        code blank : false;
        code unique: true;
    }

    static mapping = {
    }

}
```

Comment: How you checked that properties didn't changed? Did you saved your instance?

Comment: I checked first by Evaluate Expression in IDEA, second by save instance.  If i set    def parmas_map = new HashMap()    parmas_map.put("name", "test 11111")    currencyInstance.properties = parmas_map.  It work

Answer (score 0):

I found error is my fail
1 - If I send http PUT to `http://localhost:8080/test_parmas/api/currencies/9?name=zzzzzz` and set Header Content-Type = application/json but leave empty body-data send to server.
OR
2 - If I send HTTP PUT to `http://localhost:8080/test_parmas/api/currencies/9` and set Header Content-Type = application/json and body-data (have id = 9)

```
{
"id":9
"name":"Australian dollar 111"
}
```

It work if
1 - If I send http PUT to `http://localhost:8080/test_parmas/api/currencies/9?name=zzzzzz`
or
2 - If I send HTTP PUT to `http://localhost:8080/test_parmas/api/currencies/9` and set Header Content-Type = application/json and body-data

```
{
"name":"Australian dollar 111"
}
```